# Attachment using Editable Email Extension in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using Editable Email plugin in Jenkins to attach a file with the email. The problem is that the plugin is unable to find the file to attach.

My file structure is like this - 
ReportDirectory

workspace

ReportDirectory contains the report which I want to attach. I believe that the base directory for the plugin is the workspace. So I am giving the attachment location as
../ReportDirectory/DemoReport.html.
I have also tried
ReportDirectory/DemoReport.html

and many more options. 
Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I figured it out.

The Editable Email plugin uses the Ant File Syntax for locating the attachment. When I took at the documentation for Ant File Syntax ( http://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html ), it says that

> In general, patterns are considered relative paths, relative to a task dependent base directory (the dir attribute in the case of ). Only files found below that base directory are considered. So while a pattern like ../foo.java is possible, it will not match anything when applied since the base directory's parent is never scanned for files.

Since the base directory in this case is the "workspace" and my directory "ReportDirectory" is not located in it so the Ant is not able to access it.

Two solutions exist:

1. Move the "Report Directory" somewhere in "workspace". I did not prefer this because I did not want to mess up the workspace.
2. Once the report has been created in "ReportDirectory", use your Ant\MSBuild script to copy it temporarily in the "workspace" and then the Email plugin shall be able to access it by something like **/Report.html or something.

@Amey - thanks for your efforts though :)

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is create a symbolic link from `$JENKINS_HOME/jobs/workspace/$workspace_name` to the path with your `$workspace_name`. This way worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
ReportDirectory/DemoReport.html
```

is the correct way to do it.

Please keep in mind that the path to the file and the file name is case sensitive so I assume your entering the correct name.

One more thing is to check is that the report is actually created and is located at the path mentioned by you.

Another thing you could try

```
ReportDirectory/*
```

Comment: I have tried both. It's not working. Even tried with backslash instead of forward slash. I think that Ant file syntax does not scan the parent directory of the specified base directory. Have you tried out this thing?

Comment: It works when I put the report in some directory inside the workspace.  But not otherwise. But I wanted to keep this directory at the same level as the workspace since I did not want to add anything extra in the workspace other than code.

Comment: o wait wait... it has to be inside the workspace... any reason why you dont want anything extra other than code? Cause these files get overridden each time a new build is run. If you intend to deploy it from the workspace itself after a successful build, you can always ignore these files.

Comment: I don't want any extraneous directories inside the workspace. Of course I can put the report inside the workspace and access it any time. But isn't there a way for my problem?

Comment: I have it working when the files are in some directory inside the workspace. I have not tried this out but you could try typing out the full path ... `~/users/vaibhav/jenkins/DemoReport.html`

Comment: and you dont need to create a directory as such, you can directly create your report in the folder you run your code from, and then try to attach it from that folder.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21299/discussion-between-amey-and-kumar-vaibhav)

Comment: @KumarVaibhav, 
Well if my answered helped you out, please mark my answer as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins will use the directory available in its workspace.

You can send multiple attachments as below.

reportFolder/html/index.html, screenShotsFolder/screenShots/*.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer:
Copy your file into the workspace(into your job directory), then under Attachment, just give the file name without any quotation or anything. This will automatically tell Jenkins to pick up your file. That's it!
 Pls don't confuse yourself after seeing all the configurations.