# How to attach extent reports in email body through jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, extentreports

I need to attach my extent reports in email which i sent to my clients through jenkins, Mail is sending but i need the report also with email

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [extended email plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin).

It has support for what you need

Answer (score 0):

Use Email ext plugin and you have to give the path of the HTMl that needs to be attached. Please follow the below links
[Attachment using Editable Email Extension in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13926024/attachment-using-editable-email-extension-in-jenkins)

Or

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=agx0blIpErw